# Releasing a file write lock in C?

Tags: c, file-io

I am facing this strange problem, answer to which is clear to me but I am looking for alternative here. Whenever I open a file in "a+" mode, I am able to read using fread(), if I read it first and then write in it using fprintf(). If I instead write into file first and then read it, I get blank value in output. 
I do not want to fclose() the FILE pointer fp after every write because I am doing operations like write->read->write->read.......n iterations.

Is there an optimal way to achieve this ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

int main(){

FILE * fp;
fp = fopen("myback.txt", "a+");
char buf[10];

fprintf(fp, "checking");

fread (buf,1,4,fp);
buf[4] = '\0'; //buf has read n bytes   
printf("%s \n", buf);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check fread's return value to make sure it's actually reading data.

Comment: so the thing is when I do fread() -> fprintf(), it reads the data, when I do the opposite order i.e fprintf() -> fread(), it doesnt. fprintf() acquires the fp I guess and doesnt allow fread() to proceed in the latter case.

Comment: You should also read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) for fopen and append extended mode very carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this `fopen` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen):

> In update mode (`'+'`), both input and output may be performed, but output cannot be followed by input without an intervening call to `fflush`, `fseek`, `fsetpos` or `rewind`, and input cannot be followed by output without an intervening call to `fseek`, `fsetpos` or `rewind`, unless the input operation encountered end of file. In update mode, implementations are permitted to use binary mode even when text mode is specified.

So you can't read or write directly after each other, you must explicitly set or reset the file position between each input and output function.

Comment: If that is the case, why does a fread() followed by a fwrite() works ?

Comment: @Moose Because behavior is unspecified (or possibly even undefined), no one but the implementors of the code could help you with that. If you want your behavior to be well-defined and working portably, then you need to follow the rules set out in the C specification.

Comment: that makes sense. fprintf followed by fread started working after I inserted fseek in between these two operation. Thanks. I ll sleep tonight without knowing that why the fread() followed by fprintf() works though. Strange !
thanks a lot though.